# Get the highest date row from DataTable in c# using linq or data view filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm able to get the highest *date column value* but i want the whole *single datarow* whose date is highest.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("City Name");
dt.Columns.Add("date");
dt.Rows.Add("Mumbai", "17/07/2018");
dt.Rows.Add("Surat", "17/02/2018");
dt.Rows.Add("Borivali", "17/10/2018");
dt.Rows.Add("Pune", "10/05/2018");
dt.Rows.Add("Valsad", "17/09/2018");

var query = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest changing format: when working with `DateTime` why should we use `String`?

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  dt.Columns.Add("City Name");
  dt.Columns.Add("date");

  dt.Rows.Add("Mumbai",   new DateTime(2018,  7, 17));
  dt.Rows.Add("Surat",    new DateTime(2018,  2, 17));
  dt.Rows.Add("Borivali", new DateTime(2018, 10, 17));
  dt.Rows.Add("Pune",     new DateTime(2018,  5, 10));
  dt.Rows.Add("Valsad",   new DateTime(2018,  9, 17));
```

You are looking for `ArgMax` which is *not* supported by standard *Linq*, but can be easily *emulated* via `Aggregate`:

```
  var row = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Aggregate((s, a) => Convert.ToDateTime(s[1]) > Convert.ToDateTime(a[1]) ? s : a);

  Console.Write($"{row[0]} {row[1]:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

Outcome:

```
  Borivali 17/10/2018
```

In case you insist on the *original* format, you have to *parse* `string`s into `DateTime`:

```
  var row = dt
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Aggregate((s, a) => 
         DateTime.ParseExact(s[1].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >
         DateTime.ParseExact(a[1].ToString(), "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
       ? s : a);
```

Comment: how aggregate works here ? , is this making list of all rows first and then comparing one by one ?  can you explain little bit .

Comment: @Tiger: Aggregate starts from the first row, assign it to `s` then enumerate all the other rows, producing new aggegated value from current row `a` and `s` (which is previous rows aggregated)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `PersonModel` to carry your property from DataTable.

You need to let `"17/07/2018"` string to DateTime so use `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

Then the `PersonModel` class need to implement `IComparable` interface, to tell `MAX` function how to compare.

```
public class PersonModel : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dt { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        var compareObj = obj as PersonModel;
        return compareObj.Dt > this.Dt? 0:1;
    }
}

var query = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(x => 
    new PersonModel {
        Name = x[0].ToString(),
        Dt = DateTime.ParseExact(x[1].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    }
);
```